# R -- plotrix -- multhist() -- How to change the bin labels?

Tags: r, histogram, plotrix

I want to change the bin labels when using the `multhist`-function from the plotrix package. By bin labels, I mean the `labels` under each set of columns in the histograms.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to provide names to your breaks intervals, just as you would with the `names.arg` argument in `barplot`:

```
# install.packages("plotrix")
library(plotrix)

set.seed(1)
l <- list(rnorm(50),rnorm(50,sd=2),rnorm(50,mean=3))
breaks <- pretty(unlist(l))
levs <- levels(cut(unlist(l), breaks=breaks))
multhist(l, breaks=breaks, names.arg = levs)
```

[image]